# How to add an if condition to regex on Golang to match only if the group exists in Golang

Tags: regex, go, conditional-statements

I am testing two strings and want a common regex to be applied based on the condition if one group exists then apply the Regex Pattern, else other Pattern, but some reason on Regex online editor it seems that the ?=() is not recognized to add if else condition.

I have the following 2 test strings:

`/public/weltweit/nfsk/2022/05/18/668e9f57-30be-40b6-bc85-5bf66671e41d/668e9f57-30be-40b6-bc85-5bf66671e41d_AVC-270.mp4`

Expected extraction using `^\/(\bpublic\b[\/])*(.+[a-z]{1,}.*[\/|_]+)+.*?$` is

`weltweit/nfsk/2022/05/18/668e9f57-30be-40b6-bc85-5bf66671e41d/668e9f57-30be-40b6-bc85-5bf66671e41d_`

which is expected but for the other test string :

`/medp/ondemand/weltweit/fsk0/258/2580407/2580407_40256616.mp4`   with same Regex I get `medp/ondemand/weltweit/fsk0/258/2580407/2580407_`

My expected extraction is `**medp/ondemand/weltweit/fsk0/258/2580407/**`
I want to add a if condition to a group `(\bpublic\b[\/])` so that an underscore `**_**`is chosen if the group exists; otherwise a slash `**/**`

Any pointers is appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^/(?:public/(.*_)|(.*/))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Uptz2g/1). The result is either in Group 1 or Group 2.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `/` - a slash
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `public/` - a fixed string
  - `(.*_)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then a `_` char
  - `|` - or
  - `(.*/)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then a `/` char
- `)` - end of the group.

Comment: Needed to add .* at the end to match. Thanks for the answer. This worked `^/(?:public/)?(?:(?:(?:.*_)|(.*/).*))$` as I needed Group 1 to have the match.

Comment: @TilakVarisetty Then ``^/(?:public/)?(?:.*_|(.*/).*)$`` will do. However, this `.*` and `$` still look redundant.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :) Yes got rid of $ and still matches.